# How to detect click on underlaying image through transparent areas of other images?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, transparency, hittest, starling-framework

I have an image which has some transparent areas. It is displayed multiple times and overlaps (with other instances of it).
The user should be able to click on underlaying instances of the image by clicking on transparent areas of the overlaying instances.

I tried to do this by using

```java
this.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH, onTouch);
protected function onTouch(event:TouchEvent):void {
if (event.getTouch(this, TouchPhase.BEGAN))
{
    var touch:Touch = event.getTouch(this, TouchPhase.BEGAN);
    var image:Image = event.touches[0].target as Image;
}
```

But this approach does not seem to differ between transparent and non-transparent areas.

I've read that it should be possible to overwrite the `Image`-class of flash to store alpha-values, but I wasn't able to find a working example. And maybe there's a solution build-in in starling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try this solution. It seams it handles the same problem that you are having.

http://aphall.com/2012/12/starling-transparent-textures/

Comment: I had to modify it to make it work with static instances (in order to avoid problems when the same image is used very often, but it solved my problem! Thanks!